# подключение базы Ms sql server2008 к Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, sql-server, windows-server

Здравствуйте, такое дело база данных находится на удалённой машине в приделах сеть...айпишник того компьютера пингуется, соответственно связь с ним есть.
Но когда захожу в вижуал студио и добавляю новый источник данных ввожу сервер логин и пароль пользователя бд её не находит
Уже пробовал и в настройках открывать тспс айпи протокол и порт открывать брандмаузере ничего не помагает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Browser запущен на компьютере, где установлена БД?
Доступа нет только с вашего компьютера или с любого другого.

попробуйте подключиться к серверу через телнет
telnet 1433
если по этому порту нет ответа, значит надо смотреть настройки брандмауэра.

Проверьте название инстанса, возможно, что он не дефолтный.